Android BLE Extended Advertising: ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE Despite Extended Advertising Support
BLE application in Android and trying to use extended advertising to send a payload larger than the standard 31-byte limit. However, I keep encountering the following error in the logs:
Device supports extended advertising.Total Possible Length: 192
Service Data: Key: 0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, Value Size: 28 bytes, Total Size: 46 bytes (UUID: 16 + Value: 28 + Overhead: 2)
Flags: Fixed Size: 3 bytes
Total Advertisement Size: 49 bytes
Advertisement data is too large.

The error Advertisement data is too large is thrown despite the total size being only 49 bytes.
Steps I’ve Taken:

Verified Extended Advertising Support
if (bluetoothAdapter?.isLeExtendedAdvertisingSupported == true) {
Log.d("Dharmik", "Device supports extended advertising.")
} else {
Log.e("Dharmik", "Device does NOT support extended advertising.")
}

Checked Maximum Advertising Data Length
val totalLength = bluetoothAdapter?.leMaximumAdvertisingDataLength
Log.d("Dharmik", "Total Possible Length: $totalLength")


The log shows: Total Possible Length: 192.

Configured AdvertiseSettings for Extended Advertising:
val settings = AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
.setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
.setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH)
.setConnectable(false)
.build()

Created AdvertiseData
val serviceUUID: UUID = UUID.fromString("0000180D-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")
val staticMessage = "123456789012345678901234567" // 27 bytes
val serviceData = staticMessage.toByteArray()
val data = AdvertiseData.Builder()
.addServiceData(ParcelUuid(serviceUUID), serviceData)
.setIncludeTxPowerLevel(false)
.build()


With a 27-byte staticMessage, advertising works perfectly. However, adding 1 additional byte (28 bytes total) results in the following error:
E/Dharmik: Advertisement data is too large.

Callback Handling
private val advertiseCallback = object : AdvertiseCallback() {
override fun onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect: AdvertiseSettings) {
Log.d("Dharmik", "Advertising started successfully.")
}
override fun onStartFailure(errorCode: Int) {
when (errorCode) {
ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE -> {
Log.e("Dharmik", "Advertisement data is too large.")
}
// Other cases...
}
}
}


Additional Information:

Devices Tested:
Realme 6i (Realme RMX2002) - Android 11
Samsung S24 - Android 14
BLE Library: Default Android APIs (e.g., AdvertiseSettings, AdvertiseData)

1.Are there additional configuration steps required to enable extended advertising on Android?
2.Is it possible that the device or firmware has limitations on extended advertising despite claiming support?
3.How can I debug or resolve this error to allow larger advertisement packets?`

Three flag bytes are automatically added first.
The issue arises because of the default overhead bytes added automatically to the BLE advertisement. When calculating the size, these bytes are often overlooked.
A service data packet starts with a single byte indicating its length, followed by another byte specifying that it's a service data packet. Next, it includes the service UUID (16 bytes) and a UTF-8 encoded string of 10 bytes.
This totals exactly 31 bytes. Adding one more character, such as 'D', increases the string length to 11 bytes, making the total size 32 bytes, which exceeds the limit.
val settings = AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
    .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
    .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH)
    .setConnectable(false) // Required for extended advertising
    .build()

If extended advertising isn't feasible, split some data into the scan response packet, as this doesn't count toward the primary advertisement size:
val advertiseData = AdvertiseData.Builder()
    .addServiceUuid(ParcelUuid(serviceUUID))
    .setIncludeTxPowerLevel(false)
    .build()

val scanResponseData = AdvertiseData.Builder()
    .addServiceData(ParcelUuid(serviceUUID), serviceData)// Add additional data here
    .build()

Try above solution
